# Problems getting asynctask to load bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

After getting an outOfMemory error I wanted to load my bitmaps using an AsyncTask so I got this code sample from the android developer website and I'm having some trouble getting everything working together.

```
public class BitmapLoader {

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String orgImagePath,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(orgImagePath, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(orgImagePath, options);
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage
        // collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100,
                100);
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting an error: the method getResources() is undefined for the type BitmapLoader.BitmapWorkerTask. I'm relatively new to android so its very possible that I'm using the wrong method or something so I was hoping someone could enlighten me on the correct usage or at least point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

[link to the code i copied](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the activity context. Pass the activity context to the constructor of BitmapLoader.

```
     public class BitmapLoader {
     Context context; 
     public BitmapLoader(Context mContext)
     {
       context = mContext;
     } 
     }
```

Use `context.getResources()`

Check the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#getResources()

Comment: Thanks, you're awesome! Do you think you could help me with trying to pass in an image from the sdcard as a resource instead of from the res folders?

Comment: you need the path of the image from sdcard. search on so you will find many similar posts. if not ask a new question. i am sure the community will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem i solved it in the same way. But i used instead a FilePath, like you  needed. Here my Solution. You only have to

```
new BitmapWorkerTask(this, imageView, imageName).execute();

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private String fName;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(Context context, ImageView imageView, String res) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        fName = new File(context.getFilesDir(), res).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {

    return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(fName, 100,
            100);

    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String fName) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, padding, options);
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fName, options); ...... The rest is the same
```

The only difference is the Pah of the file "new File(context.getFilesDir(), res).getAbsolutePath();"